# Manipulate function not working possibly because of Arg?

Tags: manipulate, complex

I have the following function

```
eigen1 = 1/3*(p + sig - u2/(2^(8/3)*sig) - 3*I*ω);
```

Where

```
p = (Γ + κ1 + κ2)/2;
u1 = 36 g1^2 (-2 p + 3 κ2) + (36 g2^2 + (2 p - 3 κ1) (2 p - 3 κ2)) (4 p 
   - 3(κ1 + κ2));
u2 = (2^(2/3)*(12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2 - 4 p^2 + 6 p (κ1 + κ2) - 3 (κ1^2 + κ1 κ2 + 
   κ2^2)));
sig = ((u1 + Sqrt[u1^2 + u2^3])/16)^(1/3);
```

I am only interested in plotting the imaginary part of `eigen1` as a function of `g1` while varying the parameter `g2` and letting the other parameters (`κ1`, `κ2`, `Γ`, `ω`) take on fixed values

```
testplot1 = ComplexExpand[Im[eigen1]] /. {Γ -> 1, κ1 -> 2, κ2 -> 3, ω -> 0};
```

This should leave `testplot1` only dependent on `g1` and `g2`. But doing

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@testplot1, {g1, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All], {g2, 1, 10}]
```

returns a blank graph. I decided to print `testplot1` to see if there are any missing variables that I have yet to define, but everything in `testplot1` really is just a function of `g1` and `g2`. Printing `testplot1` gives

```
-((7 Sin[1/
    3 Arg[108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2 + 
      Sqrt[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
       4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]])/(3 2^(
  2/3) ((108 g1^2 - 
      108 g2^2 + (((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
          4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2)^(1/4)
        Cos[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
           4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]])^2 + 
    Sqrt[((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
       4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2]
      Sin[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
         4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]^2)^(1/6))) + (2 2^(1/3)
 Sin[1/3 Arg[
   108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2 + 
    Sqrt[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
     4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]])/(3 ((108 g1^2 - 
    108 g2^2 + (((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
        4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2)^(1/4)
      Cos[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
         4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]])^2 + 
  Sqrt[((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2]
    Sin[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
       4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]^2)^(1/6)) + (2 2^(1/3)
 g1^2 Sin[
 1/3 Arg[108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2 + 
    Sqrt[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
     4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]])/((108 g1^2 - 
  108 g2^2 + (((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
      4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2)^(1/4)
    Cos[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
       4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]])^2 + 
Sqrt[((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2]
  Sin[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
     4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]^2)^(1/6) + (2 2^(1/3)
 g2^2 Sin[
 1/3 Arg[108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2 + 
    Sqrt[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
     4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]])/((108 g1^2 - 
  108 g2^2 + (((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
      4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2)^(1/4)
    Cos[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
       4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]])^2 + 
Sqrt[((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2]
  Sin[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
     4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]^2)^(1/6) + (1/(6 2^(1/3)))((108 g1^2 - 
  108 g2^2 + (((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
      4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2)^(1/4)
    Cos[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
       4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]])^2 + 
Sqrt[((108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3)^2]
  Sin[1/2 Arg[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 
     4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]^2)^(1/6)Sin[1/3 Arg[
 108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2 + 
  Sqrt[(108 g1^2 - 108 g2^2)^2 + 4 (-3 + 12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2)^3]]]]]]
```

which seems long and nasty. The point is that the only variables in here are `g1` and `g2` so Manipulate should really work and I don't know what went wrong. My initial diagnosis would be that the `Arg` that appears in `testplot1` throughout was interfering with Manipulate but I am not sure if that's the real issue. I intend to vary not just `g2` but eventually all of the other parameters (`κ1`, `κ2`, `Γ`, `ω`) down the road but I cannot vary even one parameter at this point. Any thoughts?

Comment: Manipulate is working fine for me, it plots a line that is 0 everywhere. Try dropping the `ComplexExpand`, which is really only a function for manipulating the form of an equation, and then re-print `testplot` you'll see that you're trying to take the imaginary part of a real number, which is why this is 0 regardless of the values of `g1` and `g2`. It looks like there may be values of `g1` and `g2` for which this has an imaginary part, but it isn't imaginary in general.

Comment: If you use the `Re` part of `eigen1` `Manipulate` does seem to give a blank plot, so your problem still stands, but I think you could reduce this to an MWE. My guess is it has to do with some tricky evaluation, since if I copy and paste the expression for `Re[eigen1] /. {\[CapitalGamma] -> 1, \[Kappa]1 -> 2, \[Kappa]2 -> 
   3, \[Omega] -> 0}` directly into the manipulate it works.

Comment: After dropping `ComplexExpand`, I concur that there may be values of `g1` and `g2` for which it becomes imaginary, since there is a square root in the denominator and it's possible to make the argument less than 0 by picking appropriate `g1` and `g2` values. But why wouldn't manipulate take that into account when I'm varying `g1` and `g2`? Surely if I keep increasing `g1` and `g2` it should be imaginary but this is not the case even if I increase the range of `g1` and `g2` from 5 to 50 and 10 to 100 respectively

Comment: I've provided one solution to an MWE demonstrating the problem you're seeing. There might be a better answer addressing this problem already, evaluation in `Manipulate` can get hairy but there are some experts around. `DynamicModule` is a little more work, but can make things more straight forward, you might search the site for some old questions about `Manipulate` and `DynamicModule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, your plot will always give you 0, since you're trying to take the `Im` part of a real number - before you print `test1` for examination you should get rid of the `ComplexExpand`, it will be easier to interpret. Here is an MWE of the issue with `Manipulate`

```
test=y*x;
Manipulate[
Plot[test,{x,0,1}],
{y,0,1}
]
```

[image]

This gives a blank plot, one solution is:

```
test=y*x;
Manipulate[
Plot[test/.y->yy,{x,0,1}],
{yy,0,1}
]
```

[image]

Though I doubt this is the canonical way to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: After much fumbling with `Manipulate`, I do think that this is the best way to handle the function in my case. I would have never thought to redefined my variables inside `Manipulate`. I did `Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate@testplot1 /. {g2 -> gg}, {g1, 0, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {gg, 0, 15, 0.1}]` and I got what I was looking for (reasonably). Thanks @N.J.Evans !